# Как в React, при итерации в map, указать в src у img ссылку на файл?

Tags: reactjs

Допустим, есть 3 импорта:

import **facebook** from '../../../assets/svg/facebook.svg';

import **github** from '../../../assets/svg/github.svg';

import **instagram** from '../../../assets/svg/instagram.svg';

При запросе с Api возвращается объект:
{'facebook': null, 'github': null, 'instagram': null}

Я итерируюсь по нему в компоненте, передавая в компоненту Contacts два значения, например **contactTitle =  'facebook'**, contactValue = null:

[image: И далее в компоненте Contacts отрисовываю:]

И я расчитывал, что у img в src={contactTitle} подставиться импортированый файл, например: при первой итерации contactTitle = 'facebook', значит подтянется импортированный файл facebook, но этого не произошло.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Покажите кодом, как вы заполняете переменные и как итерируетесь по полученным данным(не зря же map  в вопросе указан). Пока предположение, что вы передаете текст, а не картинку. Код должен быть представлен текстом, а не скринами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде `src={contactTitle}` Вы присваиваете атрибуту `src` значение переменной `contactTitle`, которое является простой строкой, например `"facebook"`. Связи между строкой `"facebook"` и импортированным изображением `facebook` никакой нет.

Предлагаю реализовать эту связь через дополнительный объект вида:

```
const images = {
  "facebook": facebook,
  "github": github,
  "instagram": instagram,
}
```

А атрибуту `src` присваивать значение свойства этого объекта, найденное по совпадению значения переменной `contactTitle` и ключа свойства объекта:

```
<img src={images[contactTitle]} />
```